# CakePHP JSON extension?

Tags: json, rest, cakephp

I've created a simple REST service that serves data as XML. I've managed to enable XML, JS and RSS format but I can not find the way to enable JSON format. Is JS == JSON? Guess not :).

How can I enable this in version 1.2/1.3?

Thx!!

Answer (score 3):

Router::parseExtensions('json');

Answer (score 2):

If you have PHP 5.2 or higher, it ships with JSON encode/decode support.  [Check the docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php).

You'll probably need to do the encoding/output by hand, but it should be trivial to code.

Bonus points would be to build it as a behavior :)

Edit:

Check out the `$javascript->object()` method [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/349/Methods), it may do what you want.

Comment: I'm talking about CakePHP framework and the aoutomatization (.xml, .js, .rss... .json? ).

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search indicates that there are is a json Component for CakePHP.  Link to article discussing its use in Cake 1.2: http://www.pagebakers.nl/2007/06/05/using-json-in-cakephp-12/

Answer (score 0):

just add this line of code in your controller or AppController

```
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

function beforeFilter() {
    $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'text/x-json');
}
```

and run it into internet explorer.